# Setting static content in a UIScrollView through XIB

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiscrollview, xib

I need a `UIScrollview` to show some static content in my app.  I have taken a `UIScrollView` through `XIB` and started adding some `UIImageView`s and textViews in to it. But after coming to the end of the scrollView the view is not exapanding anymore.  I need more space so that I can add some more views below. Is there any way in which I can do this (*through `XIB` and not through code*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is you can define the height of the `UIScrollView` simply for example `height:1800`
now you get bigger `UIScrollView` then your view you can put your objects to scrollview, and if it is filled simply pull it upward and drag and drop other items when you are finished simply pull the scroll view to its position and you have it.
It is simple :)
Hope it helps
Ask if you have any other question

Comment: @ Csabi: Hi bro.. i tried both the ways before asking this question but they dint work. I tried it ones again after seeing ur reply but still im out of luck.. can you tell me a bit more on this please

Comment: it worked for me Csabi. Actually i made a silly mistake. But now when i run the program, i am unable to scroll or zoom the view... can you please tell me the reason for it????

Comment: For scrolling, you need to set the contentSize property of the scrollview (usually simply to the value of .bounds.size for the UIView that you are displaying in the scrollview).  For zooming, you must implement the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol somewhere -- probably your view controller and provide -viewForZoomingInScrollView:.

Comment: Sorry i wasnt near to comp today...so yes check if you have the height set, i rather set it in my program by code, but you can do it in ib too, and check that you have enabled the scrolling.until than bye

Comment: @: Seamus Campbell: hi seam, actually i have created my scrollview through XIB, can you please tell me how to set the contentSize for this.. Cani set this through XIB or should i do it through code???

Comment: @Csabi: i have set scrollView's height to 1600 through attributes inspector, but still my scrollView is not scrolling.

Comment: Hi guys.... Thanku for ur replies...i'v set the content size and it started scrolling.. thanku so  much again...

Answer (score 13):

I struggled a lot to get this done in a more elegant way then the solution described by Csabi.
It's really simple:

1. In your xib file just add a generic view which is not a subview of your viewController.view (i.e although this view is in your xib file, it is not a part of your viewController's view hierarchy.)
2. Then select this view and using size inspector set the width and height that suits your need. Add whatever objects you want to this view. Hook up this view to your viewController with an IBOutlet. (Let's call it IBOutlet UIView *myBigView).
3. in your viewController.view drag a ScrollView and adjust the size of the scroll view as you like. Hook this up to your viewController. (IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView)
4. Now it's super simple:

   ```
   -(void) viewDidLoad{
       [super viewDidLoad];    
       self.scrollView.contentSize = self.myBigView.bounds.size;
       [self.scrollView addSubview:self.myBigView]; 
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this did help.
Just a small correction: addSubview not addSubView.
[self.scrollView addSubview:self.myBigView];

Comment: Good Answer Raunak. Only one Issue. Custom UIViews is NOT allowed in Storyboards